# cx_Freeze: Python error in main script - what means this error message?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, runtime-error, executable, cx-freeze

In my program i have a GUI (main thread) with some subthreads and one process. In the main script i use the following statements:

```
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

The process P is started in subthread ST and communicates with this subthread ST via queues:

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
...
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=complexFct, args=prArgs)
process.start()
...
```

The subthread ST sends the messages from process X to the main GUI thread via signals:

```
PySide.QtCore.Signal()
...
```

In the main GUI thread the messages are output in textEdit field.

I create an executable of my script with cx_freeze:

```
setyp.py:
from cx_Freeze import setup
from cx_Freeze import Executable
...
```

If i start my programm.py file it works, but i have one small delay at some moment.

If i start my programm.exe file it works, but i have one delay at some moment and then i get the following error message. After the following error message, the remaining messages are outputted.

[image]

In the line 58 i have the statement

```
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

I don't understand this error message. Can you help me?

Python 3.4.2, cx_Freeze 4.3.4

Comment: It means that sys.stdout is None (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html) for some reason. What version of Python are you using, 2 or 3? And does the multiprocessing library support the same python version?

Comment: @Attilio I use Python 3.4.2 and cx_Freeze 4.3.4. The multiprocessing library was in Python 3.4.2 with it. I did not install the multiprocessing library separately: I assume that is the same version as python.

Comment: `sys.stdout` is typically None when you freeze a program as a Windows GUI. See [this bug report](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/60/python-333-freeze_support) for a workaround.

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks, but how can i set sys.stdout and sys.stderr to some objects with no-op? Where do I do that?

Comment: @ThomasK I got it! I use the fake stdout object in my process function! It works without error message now. Thank you!